# Generated non-stationary Data and auto.arima in R

Tags: r, time-series, analytics

I generated my own fictional Sales Data in order to execute a time series analysis.

It is supposed to represent a growing company and therefore i worked with a trend. However, I read through some tutorials and often read the information, that non-stationary time series should not be predicted by the auto.arima function.

But I receive results that make sense and If I would difference the data (which i did as well) the output doesn't make much sense.

So here comes my question: **Can I use the `auto.arima` function with my data, that obviously has a trend?**

Best regards and thanks in advance,
Francisco

```
eps <- rnorm(100, 30, 20)
trend <- seq(1, 100, 1)
trend <- 3 * trend
Sales <- trend + eps
timeframe<-seq(as.Date("2008/9/1"),by="month",length.out=100)
Data<-data.frame(Sales,timeframe) 

plot(Data$timeframe,Data$Sales)

ts=ts(t(Data[,1]))
plot(ts[1,],type='o',col="black")

md=rwf(ts[1,],h=12,drift=T,level=c(80,95))
auto.arima(ts[1,])
```

Using the forecast function allows us to plot the expected sales for the next year: `plot(forecast(auto.arima(ts[1,]),h=12))`

Using the forecast function with our automated ARIMA can help us plan for       the next quartal

```
forecast(auto.arima(ts[1,]),h=4)
plot(forecast(auto.arima(ts[1,])))
```

another way would be to use the autoplot function

```
fc<-forecast(ts[1,])
autoplot(fc)
```

The next step is to analyze our time-series. I execute the [adf test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test), which has the null-hypothesis that the data is non-stationary. 
So with the 5% default threshold our p-value would have to be greater than 0.05 in order to be certified as non-stationary.

```
library(tseries)
adf=adf.test(ts[1,])
adf
```

The output suggests that the data is non-stationary:

```
acf
acf=Acf(ts[1,])
Acf(ts[1,])
```

The autocorrelation is decreasing almost steadily, this points to non-stationary data also. Doing a `kpss.test` should verify that our data is non-stationary, since its null-hypothesis is the opposite of the adf test.

Do we expect a value smaller than 0.05

```
kpss=kpss.test(ts[1,])
kpss
```

We receive a p-value of 0.01, further proving that the data has a trend

```
ndiffs(ts[1,])

diff.data=diff(ts[1,])
auto.arima(diff.data)
plot(forecast(diff.data))
```

Comment: I think this question is more suited to be asked in Cross Validated.

Comment: To make your example more reproducible, always use `set.seed()` when you use random generators

Comment: Are you asking if you can use `auto.arima` on data with a trend, or how to generate data that doesn't have a trend, or both? It seems like most of your code is simply to show your data doesn't have a trend. If that is the case, you should remove all that, and just say your data has a trend. Either way, please try to condense this question to the bare minimum needed to communicate your question.

Comment: Hello Travis,
I want to make sure, that i can use auto.arima on data with a trend.

I read on this article "http://www.dataperspective.info/2014/04/time-series-analysis-using-r.html" the following : 
Differencing:
"Based on the unit test results we identify whether the data is stationary or not. If the data is stationary then we choose optimal ARIMA models and forecasts the future intervals. If the data is non- stationary, then we use Differencing "

So therefore I wanted to make sure that I can go with the auto.arima function, which worked for my case.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question - **yes**, you can use the auto.arima() function in the forecast package on non-stationary data.

If you look at the help file for auto.arima() (by typing ?auto.arima) you will see that it explains that you can choose to specify the "d" parameter - this is the order of differencing - first order means you difference the data once, second order means you difference the data twice etc. You can also choose not to specify this parameter and in this case, the auto.arima() function will determine the appropriate order of differencing using the "kpss" test. There are other unit root tests such as the Augmented Dickey-Fuller which you can choose to use in the auto.arima function by setting test="adf". It really depends on your preference.

You can refer to page 11 and subsequent pages for more information on the auto.arima function here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf